I want to drop some tables on postgres 11 master node but not the replica node ,How can i do it?
I want to drop some tables on postgres 11`s master node,
but not the replica node ,
How can i do it? I suppose i can disable logging on drop table session..

What sort of replication?

Why you want to drop on master and preserve in replica?

We use logical replica . Bascially ,replica can be seen as an data warehouse with mass diskspace ; while master`s data need to be cleaned periordically for small diskspace reason.we use middleware to complete the task.
